# Validate a javascript structure against an expected template

Tags: c#, javascript, validation

I want to validate javascript (not json) against a template before saving it in the database.

Example thing to validate:

```
(function () {
    return [{
            name: "bla",
            validation: function() { 
                alert('juhu');
            }
        },
        {
            name: "foo",
            optionalThing: {
                id: "nomnoms"
            }
        }]
    }; 
}());
```

The returned object's structure is not set in stone, but I would prefer to keep it simple (minimal validation hints and such). My goal is to check if the object is valid. It would have a fixed number of properties (with fixed names), some required, some optional. Also some general validation such as missing commas, etc. Since it has functions, JSON validation is not viable.

I would like to know if there's a C# lib that I could utilize to preform this validation based on some configuration that I put together.

I guess it could be validated on the client side before sending it to the server for saving, but I don't want to "outsource" validation if avoidable. Still, if push comes to shove, is there some lib that I could utilize instead of doing `if (model.name !== null)` and such by hand.